# Are the random variables $X$ and $f(X)$ dependent?

Tags: probability, random-variable

Can we say anything about the dependence of a random variable and a function of a random variable? For example is $X^2$ dependent on $X$?

Comment: If $X$ and $f(X)$ are independent, then $f(X)$ is constant almost surely. That is, there exists $a$ such that $\mathbb P(f(X) = a) = 1$.

Comment: @cardinal -why not make that an _answer_?

Comment: @cardinal, I wanted to ask John to elaborate on his comment. I took it for granted that the function considered was a given, deterministic function. In the process, I ended up writing out an argument for the result you stated instead. Any comments are most welcome and appreciated.

Comment: Yes, $X^2$ is dependent on $X$, since if you know $X$ then you know $X^2$.  $X$ and $Y$ are only independent if knowledge of the value $X$ did not affect your knowledge of the distribution of $Y$.

Comment: @Henry, unless, of course, $(X+1)/2$ is a Bernoulli $p$ random variable. ;-) (Then $X$ and $X^2$ are independent.)

Comment: @cardinal: I think you meant $(X-1)/2$

Comment: @Henry, No, I'm pretty sure I meant what I first wrote. If $(X+1)/2 \in \{0,1\}$ then $X \in \{-1,1\}$ and so $X^2 = 1$ almost surely. Have I gotten my head turned around? :)

Comment: I am not sure I understand the Bernoulli part. Can you add more details to your answer?

Comment: @iamrohitbanga: If $X \in \{-1,1\}$ then $X^2 = 1$ almost surely. So, $X$ is independent of $X^2$ in this very particular case.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a proof of @cardinal's comment with a small twist. If $X$ and $f(X)$ are independent then
$$ 
\begin{array}{lcl}
P(X \in A \cap f^{-1}(B)) & = & P(X \in A, f(X) \in B) \\
& = & P(X \in A) P(f(X) \in B) \\ 
& = & P(X \in A) P(X \in f^{-1}(B))
\end{array}
$$
Taking $A = f^{-1}(B)$ yields the equation 
$$P(f(X) \in B) = P(f(X) \in B)^2,$$
which has the two solutions 0 and 1. Thus $P(f(X) \in B) \in \{0, 1\}$ for all $B$. In complete generality, it's not possible to say more. If $X$ and $f(X)$ are independent, then $f(X)$ is a variable such that for any $B$ it is either in $B$ or in $B^c$ with probability 1. To say more, one needs more assumptions, e.g. that singleton sets $\{b\}$ are measurable.

However, details at the measure theoretic level do not seem to be the main concern of the OP. If $X$ is real and $f$ is a real function (and we use the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, say), then taking $B = (-\infty, b]$ it follows that the distribution function for the distribution of $f(X)$ only takes the values 0 and 1, hence there is a $b$ at which it jumps from $0$ to $1$ and $P(f(X) = b) = 1$.

At the end of the day, the answer to the OPs question is that $X$ and $f(X)$ are generally dependent and only independent under very special circumstances. Moreover, the Dirac measure $\delta_{f(x)}$ always qualifies for a conditional distribution of $f(X)$ given $X = x$, which is a formal way of saying that knowing $X = x$ then you also know exactly what $f(X)$ is. This special form of dependence with a degenerate conditional distribution is characteristic for functions of random variables.

Comment: (+1) Sorry. As I was composing my answer, I didn't get an update that you'd submitted one as well. :)

Answer (score 23):

**Lemma**: Let $X$ be a random variable and let $f$ be a (Borel measurable) function such that $X$ and $f(X)$ are independent. Then $f(X)$ is constant almost surely. That is, there is some $a \in \mathbb R$ such that $\mathbb P(f(X) = a) = 1$.

The proof is below; but, first, some remarks. The Borel measurability is just a technical condition to ensure that we can assign probabilities in a reasonable and consistent way. The "almost surely" statement is also just a technicality.

The essence of the lemma is that if we want $X$ and $f(X)$ to be independent, then our only candidates are functions of the form $f(x) = a$.

Contrast this with the case of functions $f$ such that $X$ and $f(X)$ are *uncorrelated*. This is a much, *much* weaker condition. Indeed, consider *any* random variable $X$ with mean zero, finite absolute third moment and that is symmetric about zero. Take $f(x) = x^2$, as in the example in the question. Then $\mathrm{Cov}(X,f(X)) = \mathbb E Xf(X) = \mathbb E X^3 = 0$, so $X$ and $f(X) = X^2$ are uncorrelated.

Below, I give the simplest proof I could come up with for the lemma. I've made it *exceedingly verbose* so that all the details are as obvious as possible. If anyone sees ways to improve it or simplify it, I'd enjoy knowing.

**Idea of proof**: Intuitively, if we know $X$, then we know $f(X)$. So, we need to find some event in $\sigma(X)$, the sigma algebra generated by $X$, that relates our knowledge of $X$ to that of $f(X)$. Then, we use that information in conjunction with the assumed independence of $X$ and $f(X)$ to show that our available choices for $f$ have been severely constrained.

**Proof of lemma**: Recall that $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if for all $A \in \sigma(X)$ and $B \in \sigma(Y)$, $\renewcommand{\Pr}{\mathbb P}\Pr(X \in A, Y \in B) = \Pr(X \in A) \Pr(Y \in B)$. Let $Y = f(X)$ for some Borel measurable function $f$ such that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Define $\newcommand{\o}{\omega}A(y) = \{\o: f(X(\o)) \leq y\}$. Then,
$$
A(y) = \{\o: X(\o) \in f^{-1}((-\infty,y])\}
$$
and since $(-\infty,y]$ is a Borel set and $f$ is Borel-measurable, then $f^{-1}((-\infty,y])$ is also a Borel set. This implies that $A(y) \in \sigma(X)$ (by *definition*(!) of $\sigma(X)$).

Since $X$ and $Y$ are assumed independent and $A(y) \in \sigma(X)$, then
$$
\Pr(X \in A(y), Y \leq y) = \Pr(X \in A(y)) \Pr(Y \leq y) = \Pr(f(X) \leq y) \Pr(f(X) \leq y) \>,
$$
and this holds for all $y \in \mathbb R$. But, by definition of $A(y)$
$$
\Pr(X \in A(y), Y \leq y) = \Pr(f(X) \leq y, Y \leq y) = \Pr(f(X) \leq y) \> .
$$
Combining these last two, we get that for *every* $y \in \mathbb R$,
$$
\Pr(f(X) \leq y) = \Pr(f(X) \leq y) \Pr(f(X) \leq y) \>,
$$
so $\Pr(f(X) \leq y) = 0$ or $\Pr(f(X) \leq y) = 1$. This means there must be some constant $a \in \mathbb R$ such that the distribution function of $f(X)$ jumps from zero to one at $a$. In other words, $f(X) = a$ almost surely.

**NB**: Note that the converse is also true by an even simpler argument. That is, if $f(X) = a$ almost surely, then $X$ and $f(X)$ are independent.

Comment: +1, I should be sorry - to steal your argument is not very polite. It's great that you spelled out the difference between independence and being uncorrelated in this context.

Comment: No "stealing" involved, nor impoliteness. :) Though many of the ideas and comments are similar (as you'd expect for a question like this!), I think the two posts are nicely complementary. In particular, I like how at the beginning of your post you didn't constrain yourself to real-valued random variables.

Comment: @NRH accepting your answer as the initial part of your proof seems easier to grasp for a novice like me. Nevertheless +1 cardinal for your answer.