# Can someone help to explain the difference between independent and random?

Tags: distributions, sampling, randomness

In statistics, does independent and random describe the same characteristics? What's the difference between them? We often come across the description like "two independent random variables" or "random sampling". I am wondering what's the exact difference between them. Can someone explain this and give some examples? for instance non-independent but random process?

Comment: Here is two distinct (on a not very deep level) concepts merged. "Independent" in the sense independently generated observations, and "independent variables" wrt their distributions.

Comment: This is a strange question, because if you were to consult formal definitions of "random variable" and "independent"--which is what "in statistics" would seem to suggest--you would find they have little in common.

Comment: @ttnphns, Yes, I guess I was more confused about the term "independently generated observations" with "randomly generated". In sampling, we often hear (simple) random sampling, which makes me feel like independent samples. I guess if we really want to combine both characteristics in describing a sampling method, it should be: the selection of observations is not dependent on each other (=independently) and the probability of selection an observation is known (=randomly)?

Comment: Another issue is that I wonder why the term "independent sampling" is not often mentioned? Could it happen that two observations are independently selected however they are dependent? For instance in a simple random sampling with replacement, I would independently select observations, but 2 identical observations are selected due to sampling with replacement. Does this mean that these two observations are dependent?

Comment: If we check the definition of independence from wiki: "In probability theory, two events are independent, statistically independent, or stochastically independent if the occurrence of one does not affect the probability of the other.", the dependency of two observations should be based on how they are generated/selected, rather than how they look like in the data. Then the two identical observations in the case I mentioned above should still be independent.

Comment: Please do not confuse the heuristic explanation at the beginning of any Wikipedia entry with a definition. The definition is given under the heading "definition" [in the same article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#For_events).  It is the one offered in Tim's answer here.

Comment: However, when we apply mixed models to nested data, we often state that some observations are not-independent, just based on the data structure. But if these observations are indeed independently selected, how come they become non-independent? or the non-independence here refers to the random variable that we want to estimate in the model?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'll try to explain it in non-technical terms: A random variable describes an outcome of an experiment; you can not know in advance what the exact outcome will be but you have some information: you know which outcomes are possible and you know, for each outcome, its probability.

For example, if you toss a fair coin then you do not know in advance whether you will get head or tail, but you know that these are the possible outcomes and you know that each has 50% chance of occurrence.

To explain independence you have to toss two fair coins. After tossing the first coin you know that for the second toss the probabilities of head is still 50% and for tail also. If the first toss has no influence on the probabilities of the second one then both tosses are independent. If the first toss has an influence on the probabilities of the second toss then they are dependent.

An example of dependent tosses is when you glue the two coins together.

Comment: Another pair of dependent variables would be "whether you got heads" and "whether you got tails". Both are random but they are not independent of each other.

Comment: @immibis Or roll a fair dice, write down the value. then roll it once more and multiply the value with the value written down. This value is random, but dependent on the first roll.

Answer (score 8):

*Random* relates to [random variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50/what-is-meant-by-a-random-variable), and *independent* relates to probabilistic independence. By [independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)) we mean that observing one variable does not tell us anything about the another, or in more formal terms, if $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables, then we say that they are independent if

$$ p_{X,Y}(x, y) = p_X(x)\,p_Y(y) $$

moreover

$$ E(XY) = E(X)E(Y) $$

and their covariance is zero. Random variable $Y$ is dependent on $X$ if it can be written [as a function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16321/are-the-random-variables-x-and-fx-dependent) of $X$

$$ Y = f(X) $$

So in this case $Y$ is *random* and *dependent* on $X$.

Calling process "non-independent" is pretty misleading - independent of what? I guess you meant that there are some $X_1,\dots,X_k$ independent and identically distributed random variables (check [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17391/what-are-i-i-d-random-variables/17392#17392), or [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213464/on-the-importance-of-the-i-i-d-assumption-in-statistical-learning)) that come from some process. By independent we would mean in here that they are independent of each other. There are processes producing dependent random variables, e.g.

$$ X_i = X_{i-1} + \varepsilon $$

where $\varepsilon$ is some random noise. Obviously in such case $X_i$ is dependent on $X_{i-1}$, but it is also random.

Comment: What does $P(X)$ mean if X is a random variable? I think you're confusing RVs and events: two RVs X and Y are independent if the *events* $P(X\leq r)$ and $P(Y\leq s)$ are independent for all r,s

Comment: Then any two continuous random variables are independent.

Comment: @m_t_ I really do not think that discussing the notation leads anywhere (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#For_random_variables )

Comment: That's better, but the statement with f isn't right: if f is constant then so is Y= f(X), so Y is independent of X, not dependent on X.

Comment: @m_t_ this is splitting hair, see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16321/are-the-random-variables-x-and-fx-dependent or http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~napkaria/crypto/handouts/IndepDepRV.pdf

Comment: Can I interpret the definition of independence p(x,y) using likelihood function as an example? If I have a dataset each observation is independent and each observation follows a pdf(randomness). The likelihood of observing such data would be a multiplication of the pdfs, which combines the independence and randomness of a sampled data into one formula

Comment: @tiantianchen the other way around: if you have iid random variables, then you can construct likelihood function by multiplying the individual pdf's *because* they are independent.

Comment: Thanks @Tim. Your answers are very clear to me. One last question: does the concept of independence only applies to random variables? We often make such statement: observation A and B are independent. So this actually refers to: the probability of observing A and probability of observing B are independent?

Comment: @tiantianchen I'm afraid your example is to vague to comment it, but *everything* we deal with in statistics are random variables, so if the statement is in context of statistics, then yes -- it's either about independent events, or independent random variables.

Answer (score 3):

The notion of independence is relative, while you can be random  by yourself. In your example, you have "two independent random variables", and do not need to talk about several "random sampling".

Suppose you cast a perfect die several times. The outcome $6,5,3,5, 4\ldots$ is a priori random. Knowing the past, you cannot predict the number following 4. Suppose I generate a sequence from the other side of the die: $6\to1$, $3\to4$. I get $1,2,4,2, 3\ldots$. It is as random as the first one. You cannot guess what comes after $3$. But the two sequences are completely dependent.

If one casts two dice in parallel (without interactions between they), their respective sequences will be random and  independent.

Comment: This may be a little technical given the level of the OP, but regarding your statement "You cannot be independent (of something) alone (as a process, a sequence)" consider the following: Any random variable X, which equals a constant c with probability one, is independent of "everything", including itself.  I.e., for such an X, X is independent of X. You can easily check that per the definition of independence.

Comment: @Mark L. Stone I shall correct this false statement. By alone I meant "in itself". In your definition, are you allowed to say: $X$ is independent, or $X$ and $X$ are independent?

Comment: X is independent of itself. I.e., X is independent of X.

Answer (score 2):

Variables are used in all fields of mathematics.  The definitions for independence and randomness of a variable are applied unilaterally to all forms of mathematics, not just to statistics.

For example, the X and Y axes in 2-dimensional Euclidean geometry represent independent variables, however, their values are not (usually) assigned at random.

Two given variables can be random, or independent (of one another), or both, or neither.  Statistics tends to focus on the randomness (more correctly, on probability), and whether or not two variables are independent can have many implications for the probabilities of given outcomes being observed.

You tend to see these two properties (independence and randomness) described together when studying statistics, because both are important to know, and can influence the answer to the question at hand.  However, these properties are not synonymous, and in other fields of mathematics they do not necessarily occur together.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain more about "whether two variables are independent can have many implications for the probabilities of given outcomes being observed."

Comment: This is a non-statistical answer that addresses a different sense of "independent" than the one used in the question.  It also confuses two senses of "variable": one is the mathematical one and the other is the statistical definition of *random variable* (which definitely is *not* the same as variables on geometric axes).

Answer (score 0):

When you have a pair of values when the first is randomly generated and the second has any dependence on the first one. e.g. height and weight of a man. There is correlation between them. But they are both random.

Comment: Although this post uses the words "random" and "dependent," it doesn't define them or clearly distinguish them.  Indeed, it seems to suggest that "random=dependent"!

Answer (score 0):

David Bohm in his work Causality and Chance in Modern Physics (London: Routledge, 1957/1984) describes causality, chance, randomness, and independence:

"In nature nothing remains constant. Everything is in a perpetual state of transformation, motion, and change. However, we discover that nothing simply surges up out of nothing without having antecedents that existed before. Likewise, nothing ever disappears without a trace, in the sense that it gives rise to absolutley nothing existing at later times. .... everything comes from other things and gives rise to other things. This principle is not yet a statement of the existence of causality in nature. To come to causality, the next step is then to note that as we study processes taking place under a wide range of conditions, we discover that inside all of the complexity of change and transformation there are *relationships* that remain effectively constant. .... At this point, however, we meet a new problem. For the necessity of a causal law is never absolute. Thus, we see that one must conceive of the law of nature as necessary only if one abstracts from *contingencies*, representing essentially independent factors which may exist outside the scope of things that can be treated by the laws under consideration, and which do not follow necessarily from anything that may be specified under the context of these laws. Such contingencies lead to *chance*." (pp.1-2)

"The tendency for contingencies lying outside a given context to fluctuate independently of happenings inside that context has demonstrated itself to be so widespread that one may enunciate it as a principle; namely, the principle of randomness. By randomness we mean just that this independence leads to fluctuation of these contingencies in a very complicated way over a wide range of possibliities, but in such a manner that statistical averages have a regular and approximately predictable behaviour."
(p.22)

Comment: Your definition of "random" seems unusual.  It appears to be intimately connected with concepts of "predictability" and "pattern"--but what exactly do those mean?  For instance, if an experiment that potentially could yield any number between $0$ and $1$ were consistently observed to yield values of either $1/3$ or $4/7$, that would seem to be a "pattern" and--to the extent it differs from the original infinite set of possible values--is at least partially "predictable." Where you write "if you plot..." it seems you are claiming that *no* univariate variable can be random!

Comment: @whuber When any event in a sequence of events cannot be inferred from the previous events, the sequence is random. A pattern has different motifs that are repeated. For example, the squares of a square wave. If one motif is omitted, it can be said to be a pattern if the pattern predicts completion for the omitted motif. By *pattern* I mean the sequential pattern of the variable. By *prediction*, I did not intend the outcome of the variable at time point $t$ given an expected value *range(0.0, 1.0)*, but how an arbitrary point $t_n$ cannot be predicted based on $t_n-m$ for all negative $m$s.

Comment: You seem to be discussing *stochastic processes* (in time) rather than randomness and random variables.

Comment: @whuber I fail to see how $t$ does not generalize to $x$.

Comment: I believe part of the difficulty we are having in communicating is that you appear to be thinking of "independent" in the sense of an *independent variable in regression.* Although some elements of the question might suggest that, the phrases "two independent random variables" and "random sampling" indicate otherwise.

Comment: @whuber How is your understanding of independent different from mine? Random sampling is different from conditional sampling - consider a hypergeometric distribution resulting from sampling without replacement. The samples can be drawn randomly, but the population is given a priori. The order of the sampling provides x. Perhaps it is the distinction between "random effect" and fixed effect that confuses. I don't know.

Comment: I cannot even tell what your understanding is, because your answer provides no definitions.  I'm having to guess what you're trying to say from the examples and descriptions you give.  They appear to differ from the senses of "random" and "independent" in the ways I have described in previous comments.

Comment: @whuber Described independent, you have not.

Comment: I am sorry that I have been of no help in getting your answer clarified.  Might I suggest taking a look at [Tim's answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/231432/edit) for a rigorous definition?

Comment: @whuber I do not think you have read my answer properly.

Comment: I'd add to @whuber comments that your definition mentioning random variables **influencing** each other may be misleading. "Influence" is a very strong term implicating some kind of causality etc. while the formal definition of independence does not require any causality or influence but it is simply about relations of joint vs individual probabilities.

Comment: @Tim Where do I state that random vars influence each other?

Comment: Second paragraph, you bolded it.

Comment: @Tim That's not what I said.

Comment: Your last edit with the example of blue sky and rain actually illustrates mine and @whuber's doubts: you are not talking here about probabilistic independence. Even if those two events are *caused* by an external factor and do not "depend" directly on each other, though they co-occur more often then by chance, so $p(x,y) \ne p(x)p(y)$, i.e. they are not independent by definition. You call independence "assumption", while it is rather a property of events of random variables. Even if you are talking about "dependent" and "independent" variables as understood in regression, then this needs to

Comment: be stated in your answer directly, because otherwise your answer is misleading. Independent variable in regression is something really different then independent random variables.

Comment: @whuber Tim made it clear to me that I was wrong. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Tim Thanks! It took me a while to understand that my misunderstanding was on a very basic level.

Comment: @noumenal could you consider either editing or deleting your answer? As it stands we have an answer, now sitting here untouched for half a year essentially saying "ignore this while I think about it"...

Comment: @Glen_b Sorry, I forgot about this question. I will let David Bohm answer this one.

Answer (score 0):

The coin example is a great illustration of a random and independent variable, a good good way to think of a random but dependent variable would be the next card drawn from a seven deck shoe of playing cards, the -likelihood- of any specific numerical outcome changes depending on the cards previously dealt, but until only one value of card remains in the shoe, the value of the card to come next will remain random.

Comment: Probably worth replacing the word "likelihood" by "probability" here, since [likelihood has a separate technical definition in statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function)

Comment: A probability that depends on other events (often previous events, but sometimes based on knowledge of future or simultaneous events - there actually is no temporal direction to this) is called a *conditional* probability. The word *likelihood* is used to refer to a kind of "probability in reverse" (or in the continuous case, a probability density) - that is, one calculates the probability of an outcome (e.g. your data) conditional on your model parameter(s), but if we think of this the other way round, it's the likelihood *of that parameter, given your data*.

Comment: Unless you're calculating the likelihood of a parameter, it's best to avoid the word "likelihood" in statistics, even where in normal English one would use "likelihood" as a synonym for the probability of an event (e.g. "rolling ten sixes in a row in a game of dice has a very low likelihood" is fine for colloquial English, but isn't using the word correctly in a statistical sense). "Let $π$ be a parameter denoting the probability that a biased die rolls a six; calculate the likelihood that $π=1/6$ given that ten rolls of the die were all sixes" is statistically correct but jargony