# Assume $X,Y$ are two independent random variables. Let $Z=f(X,Y)$. If $Z$ is independent of $X$, $f(X,Y)$ is constant in $X$. Is this true?

Tags: probability, random-variable, independence, random-vector

Let $X\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $Y\in \mathbb{R}^m$ be two independent random vectors. Then, say that we have a third real valued random variable $Z=f(X,Y)$, with $f$ being measurable.

- Say that we know that $Z\perp X$. Can we then say that $f(X,Y)$ is
  constant in $X$ in some sense?
- Alternatively, say that for $Y\in S$ ($S$ with positive probability), $f(X,Y)$ is not constant in $X$. Is it true then that $f(X,Y)$ is not independent of $X$?

I've seen a similar question in [this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16321/are-the-random-variables-x-and-fx-dependent?newreg=a59710d417304f27b1bddf60021e4c14): answers in this link show that if $X$ is independent of $f(X)$, then $f(X)$ must be a constant almost surely. Yet, I found it hard to adapt this argument to this case of a function $f(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, independence of $X$ and $Z$ doesn't imply independence conditional on $Y$ (equivalent to $f(X,Y)$ being constant in $X$).

For example, suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and both take values of $-1$ and $1$ with equal probability.  Suppose that $Z=f(X,Y)=XY$.  You then have the following four outcomes occuring with equal probabilities
$$
\begin{matrix}
    X & Y & Z 
\\ -1 & -1 & 1 
\\ -1 & 1 & -1
\\ 1 & -1 & -1
\\ 1 & 1 & 1
\end{matrix}
$$
Although $X$ and $Z=f(X,Y)$ are clearly independent, $f(X,Y)$ is not constant in $X$.

The second statement is the [contraposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359262/how-is-the-law-of-contraposition-a-tautology) of the first statement and so logically equivalent and not true.